# Can all stems be pinched on a plant or only the main stem?

Tags: vegetables, plant-care, leaves

I want my plant to be bushy but I have a few stems that are going out really far horizontally and they tend to get broken from the rain. Are these stems that come off the main stem safe to pinch? Will it cause growth where I pinch it or does that work only on the main stem?
Thanks!

Comment: What kind of plant?

Comment: They are Bean plants